# How to change SQLITE version of http on EC2

Tags: sqlite, apache

I have compiled and installed the latest version of SQLITE3 on my Amazon EC2 instance and when entering

```
sqlite3
```

in the shell it returns

```
SQLite version 3.38.3 2022-04-27 12:03:15
```

But when calling the PHP

```
print_r(SQLite3::version());
```

it returns

```
Array ( 
[versionString] => 3.7.17 
[versionNumber] => 3007017
 )
```

What do I need to change so that the Apache Web Server also recognizes the new SQLITE version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not call the SQLite executable. Instead, it is linked with a SQLite library. The only way to change the SQLite version which PHP uses is to change (reinstall or recompile) PHP itself.